# Formula to calculate price for N apples if per apple price changes based on the count of apples

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

Imagine I have a table like below. The table says that if the count of apples is known then we know the price per apple in that busket.

```
   Count of Apple | Price per Apple
             0-10 | 0
            11-20 | 1$
            21-30 | 2$
            31-40 | 3$
            41-50 | 4$
            51-60 | 5$
```

For example if I buy `34` apples, that means that I need to look at the 4th line `31-40 | 3$` in my table as `34` is in between `31` and `40`. Therefor, for 34 apple per apple price will be `3$` and that means `34` apples will cost `34 * 3$ = 102$`.

Example 2 would be if I have `4` apples. In this case I need to look at the first line `0-10 | 0` and here one apple costs `0$`, i.e. `4` apple price will be `4 * 0$ - 0$`.

Now it need to have in spreadsheets a table representing the information in and the formula to calculate the total price of N apples. [Here is a sample.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10syCPJh1upz-BxKZyJCJHn-eEFw180_x3NEYIh9HGqg/edit?usp=sharing) How do I get the formula?

I can calculate this by writing tones of `if` statements, but because my table might have more than 5-10 rows, it will be just impossible to do.

Comment: Updated with `=XLOOKUP(G2,A2:A9,B2:B9,,1)*G2`

Comment: Thanks @MayukhBhattacharya, this is exactly what I wanted. If you would write a full answer, I would accept it.

Comment: Just posted as is shown in the sheets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented above and as mentioned by `OP` to post as an answer.

[image]

---

Using `XLOOKUP()` --> put `1` in the **match_mode** explicitly in the fourth argument.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `H2`

```
=XLOOKUP(G2,A2:A9,B2:B9,,1)*G2
```

---

Answer (score 2):

So, apart from xlookup(), both of these versions work:

[image]

Then you can multiply by the number either in the cell F2:

```
VLOOKUP(D2,A2:B7,2,1)* D2
```

or in a separate cell:

```
=F2*D2
```